# Wikitude SDK for Cordova　の使い方がわかりません．

Tags: monaca

Wikitude SDK for Cordova　を使ってmonacaでARプログラムの開発をしたいと考えています．
まだすべてにおいて初心者なので，Wikitudeのサンプルプログラムを動かすことがまずの目標です．　　GitHub（https://github.com/Wikitude/wikitude-cordova-plugin-samples）ZipファイルをダウンロードしてMonacaでProjectをImportしようとしたのですが，次のようなエラーメッセージが出てimportできません．
Internal Server Error (500)
Neither project_info.json nor config.xml was found. Maybe an old project?

初歩的な間違いだと思うのですが，間違いを教えていただけないでしょうか．

Comment: `project_info.json も、config.xml もありません。古いプロジェクトなのではないでしょうか？`というエラーメッセージです。エラーメッセージは、ここに書くよりも、翻訳サイトを使ったほうが早いと思います。もしエラーは理解されているのであれば、古いプロジェクトをmonacaにインポートするにはどうしたらよいかをご質問された方が良いと思います。

Comment: `monaca`の設定ファイルが不足していると`Maybe an old project?`「古いプロジェクトかも？」と聞いてきますが、必ずしも古いプロジェクトであるわけではなく、そもそもの構造が違うものを入れようとしても聞いてきます。

Comment: 早速にコメントをいただき，有難うございます．
初めての投稿で，不備が色々あり申し訳ありません．
エラーの意味は大体わかったのですが，古いプロジェクトではないように思ったので，このエラーに心当たりがおありの方がおられないかと考え，投稿しました．
もう少し頑張ってみます．

Answer (score 1):

参考にしようとサンプルアプリをインポートしようとしているのですね？
ですがサンプルアプリはあくまで`Cordova`のプロジェクトです。
`monaca`は`Cordova`のフレームワークは利用していますが、
プロジェクトファイルの形態は似て非なるものです。

ですので参考になされているサンプルプロジェクトをインポートすることは出来ません。

ご自身で空のプロジェクトファイルを作成し、
WikitudeのCordovaPluginをダウンロード後インポートしてください。

呼び出し方などはドキュメントに書いてありますが、
サンプルを`monaca`に展開することは出来ないです。

Comment: 試してはいませんが、Cordovaプロジェクトのインポート自体は対応しているようです http://blog.asial.co.jp/1376

Comment: コレ去年の記事ですよね？この後の7月と10月にフレームワークごと変わる大規模アップデートがあり、`monaca`の設定ファイルが必須になったかと思います

Comment: ご親切な回答とコメントを有難うございます．
ご教授いただいた「Cordovaプロジェクトのインポートに対応しました」のページを読み，monacaの設定ファイルについて調べてみます．
上手くいかなければ，自分でプロジェクトを作る方法を試します．
途方に暮れていましたが，ヒントをいただき，助かります．

Answer (score 0):

これはついこの間作成したプロジェクトです。

https://github.com/moongift/WiktudeMonacaSample

ただ、プラグインなのでゴールドプラン以上が必要です。

Comment: ゴールドプランにしてhttp://qiita.com/moongift/items/a64c6f470ec43a50be40を見ながら試してみましたが，Androidアプリのデバッグビルドに失敗しました．ビルド設定に間違いがある可能性があります．
AndroidManifest.xml キーストアの設定を見直せと言っています．アドバイスを頂ければありがたいのですが.